# Cannot assign Nullable<Int64> to Linq.Table.Max()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, nullable

I have the following two lines of code in my program. The goal is to return the highest number from the Value field.

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
long? id = (long?)context.MyTable.Max(x => x.Value);
```

The Value field is a bigint field in the table. The table also cannot guarantee that it contains rows, in fact that it is scenario I am testing now. I am attempting to run this when MyTable has no rows.

The second line returns an invalid operation exception.

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int64 which is a non-nullable value type.

I've tried it several different ways but I am unable to get this to work. I obviously not understanding something important about nullable types in C#.

EDIT (solution):

Thanks to Chris's answer I was able to find the actual cause of my problem and solution. It turns out that it wasn't so much that the Value field was null but that since x inside the lambda expression was a null row. So I added a check inside the lambda to see if x was null, if not then I can safely check if Value is null.

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
long? id = context.MyTable.Max(x => x == null ? (long?)0 : (long?)x.Value);
```

Comment: I'm mildly surprised by that answer since the error implies that it got a value but that it was null. I'd have expected a null reference exception if it was trying to do x.Value when x was null. However, looks like you have a good answer now. And for what its worth best practice is if you come up with a solution yourself is to make that solution into an answer (rather than an edit) and mark it as the correct answer. That way the question gets an accepted answer which is separated from the question itself.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered the question myself but I do not have the requisite reputation to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your max function is trying to return an Int64. The overload of Max you are using is defined here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534740.aspx). You'll see that it takes a parameter `Func<TSource, long> selector`. This is your lambda expression and says that you'll give it a TSource and it will return a long (ie Int64). What your function is doing is when x.Value is null returning a null value which is of course not valid to as an Int64.

In this case you should be able to use something like:

```
x=> x.Value!=null?x.Value:Int64.Minvalue
```

This means that if x has a value it returns that and otherwise returns the minimum possible value which will only ever be the max if *everything* is null.

I should disclaim that this code is untested but should give you the right idea.

*edited*: I originally was assuming that this was a nullable long but it turns out there are overloads that support that so I now assume that x is not a nullable long, just looks a bit like one if you squint int eh right way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While it didn't fix my issue directly it made me realize my mistake. I needed to make sure that the x variable in my lambda expression wasn't null before checking if the x.Value was null. I posted the solution as an edit.